# How to make Vaadin CRUD combobox field binding?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Assuming I have a combo box in Vaadin CrudEditor

so this will be the code of the combo box part:

```java
        ComboBox<Driver> driversComboBox = new ComboBox<>("Drivers");
        ComboBox.ItemFilter<Driver> filter = (driver, filterString) -> 
                 driver.getFullName().toLowerCase().contains(filterString.toLowerCase());
        driversComboBox.setItems(filter, driverService.findAll());
        driversComboBox.setItemLabelGenerator(Driver::getFullName);
```

and this is the binder:

```java
        binder.forField(driversComboBox).asRequired().bind(Transporter::getDrivers, Transporter::setDrivers);
```

but this binder is wrong, I get this error:

```
Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.util.Set<org.vaadin.webinar.security.sampleapp.Entity.Driver> to org.vaadin.webinar.security.sampleapp.Entity.Driver
```

So, Transporter model:

```java
public class Transporter extends AbstractEntity{

...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transporter", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity = Driver.class)
    private Set<Driver> drivers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

So, in short, How to bind the combobox with a List?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Vaadin component but there is a 3rd party component https://vaadin.com/directory/component/multiselect-combo-box

But be aware that this component currently doesn't work with Vaadin 22. It works fine until Vaadin 21.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to bind it with the CrudEditor form?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How do you create the editor?

Comment: Sorry, your answer is correct. using that library is fine.